# How can I prevent Molecule from adding hydrogens automatically?

Tags: chemistry

Consider the following:

```
cacl = Molecule[{Atom["Ca"], Atom["Cl"]}, {Bond[{1, 2}, "Single"]}];
MoleculeValue[cacl, "CanonicalSMILES"]
(* Cl[CaH] *)
```

Notice the artificial insertion of the hydrogen atom to fill the valency of the calcium atom. I understand that this behaviour is mentioned in the [official documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Molecule.html):

"Hydrogen atoms may be omitted from the atom list if their presence can be inferred from the valence and bonding of the atoms present."

But is there a way to suppress this default behaviour? I want the SMILES representation of the molecule above to be `Cl[Ca+]`, not `Cl[CaH]`.

Comment: Unfortunately, there seems to be no way. I think this choice of default behaviour was a very short-sighted decision on the part of Wolfram Research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a SMILES string to create the molecule. In a SMILES string, wrapping an atomic symbol with brackets signifies that there should be no implicit hydrogens added.

```
mol = Molecule["[Ca][Cl]"]
```

[image]

Note that this does leave an unpaired electron on the calcium atom,

```
In[17]:= AtomList@mol

Out[17]= {Atom["Ca", "UnpairedElectronCount" -> 1], Atom["Cl"]}
```

which I think is what you are going for.

I think a reasonable way to input atoms like this would be something like

```
Molecule[{"[Ca]", "Cl"}, {Bond[{1, 2}, "Single"]}]
```

I can make the above work for 12.1

Comment: Perhaps explicitly indicating the formal charge of a specific atom might be sufficient?

Comment: I have accepted this because it answers the question as posed. Since you seem to be in charge of these features within Mathematica, it might be relevant to mention that what I would really like is the ability to *start* with the command `Molecule[atoms, bonds]` and have a way to suppress the automatic insertion of hydrogen atoms. I am doing some combinatorics on the graph structures of molecules, and generating SMILES only in the very end to record results. So, if Mathematica could accept a command like `Molecule[atoms, bonds, InsertHydrogens -> False]`, that would be awesome.

Comment: I have something like this, try `Molecule[{Atom["Ca"], Atom["Cl"]}, {Bond[{1, 2}, "Single"]}, IncludeHydrogens -> None]`.  From re-reading your question it seems you would like the calcium here to automatically be given a positive charge instead of a radical electron. I'm not sure if that is the right behavior for all applications.

Answer (score 7):

I imagine it's because CaCl is not a valid compound. If you want CaCl+, you can do:

```
cacl = Molecule[{Atom["Ca+"], Atom["Cl"]}, {Bond[{1, 2}, "Single"]}]
```

> [image]

```
MoleculeValue[cacl, "CanonicalSMILES"]
```

> "Cl[Ca+]"

For CaCl2:

```
cacl2 = Molecule[{Atom["Ca"], Atom["Cl"], Atom["Cl"]}, {Bond[{1, 2}, "Single"], Bond[{1, 3}, "Single"]}];
MoleculeValue[cacl2, "CanonicalSMILES"]
```

> "Cl[Ca]Cl"